# Virtualbox: Raw linux partition not booting in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, grub

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and I wanted to boot from usb. The command I used to create the .vmdk is:

```
vboxmanage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename /root/VirtualBox\ VMs/USB_VM2.vmdk -rawdisk /dev/sdb
```

I successfully created the .vmdk file

```
RAW host disk access VMDK file /root/VirtualBox VMs/USB_VM2.vmdk created successfully.
```

But the problem is when I attach the vmdk file to virtualbox and start the VM it always shows

```
could not read from the boot medium
```

What is going wrong with my system? I running everything in root mode, so there shouldn't be any issue with permission.

Any leads will be highly appreciated

Comment: Did you set the correct boot order? If you created this file as root you will need to adjust permissions on the vmdk file for virtualbox to be able to read it (0666 permissions possibly)

Comment: @KyleH I have set the permission 777 and boot order as the hard drive in the first preference. Still no luck

Comment: Did you set permission for both disk **and** .vmdk file?  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/284704/verr-access-denied-when-trying-to-add-a-raw-disk-to-virtual-box